# Xcode Project error: xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file

Tags: xcode

I have been scratching my hair to solve this one. Here is what happened.

I recently formatted my MAC and I synced all files back to it from my Dropbox account.

For some reason I am getting this error each time I try to open any of my Xcode projects:

`xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.`

Now, I've found several threads on stack overflow that suggest different solutions and one common is to pewit the `.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file but when checking the content of my Xcode project I can't find such a file.

I don't know what I can do anymore as my Xcode skills are highly limited and I would really be thankful if someone could put me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: 'Mac': still not an acronym.

Answer (score 9):

The Xcode project file is a package (so it's really a folder).  The project.pbxproj is stored inside the package.  Go to Finder, right-click on your project file, select Show Package Contents.  The project.pbxproj should be present.  If not, go back and do the same thing with your copy in Dropbox.

FYI, I can round trip a project file to and from Dropbox and it doesn't get corrupted.

Comment: Hi, thats the problem I have there is no such file named "project.pbxproj" no matter how many times I copy it back and forth from Dropbox! Actually, its really weird as I have tested this on other projects I have and I am facing the same issue which is really strange!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to wait for the folder (lets say Myproject) to completely sync. If there are other files to sync as brothers to Myproject then the project.pbxproj file will not be synced right away. You can move Myproject inside another newly created folder Myprojectparent outside the other brother files being synced bc the sync will be faster.